# Power shell command to delete files with 1 row

Tags: powershell

I have files sitting in a folder on windows. I need to delete files with 1 row ( Having just the header) and leave the rest in there. What would be the command to do it in power shell?

The files will be of the below pattern

Test_Files_QS1_202202080808.csv
Test_Files_QS2_202202080808.csv
Test_Files_QS3_202202080808.csv
Test_Files_QS4_202202080808.csv

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to read 2 lines from each file, if you get less than 2 then delete:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv |Where-Object {@($_ |Get-Content -TotalCount 2 |Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne '' }).Count -lt 2} |Remove-Item
```

Comment: Its not deleting the files with the above command

Comment: @rick Make sure you run it from the folder that actually contains the CSV files :)

Comment: Yes I am running from the folder the files are in.

Comment: @rick Fascinating. What does `@(Get-Content Test_Files_QS1_202202080808.csv).Count` show?

Comment: Sorry about that. Loos like the files have 2 rows in the sense they have a space in the second row and hence its not deleting. when I changed it to 3 its deleting. How can I trim the second row and then delete if it has only 1 row

Comment: @rick I see. Luckily you can nest `Where-Object` statements ;-) Answer updated